# Kernel randomly aborting

Tags: bugs, evaluation, kernel

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3**

---

So after 2 days of trying to figure out what's going on, I figure I should post here as I don't have enough knowledge about the Mathematica evaluation process "under the hood". I'm running Mathematica 10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015) on Xubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. The following code causes the "blue text of kernel death" (or whatever is the term):

```
Table[
 ParametricPlot3D[{1.16^(v + a) Cos[(v + a)] (1 + 
  Cos[u]), -1.16^(v + a) Sin[(v + a)] (1 + 
  Cos[u]), -2 1.16^(v + a) (1 + Sin[u])}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -15, 
  6}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 3}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  ImageSize -> 500, Background -> None],
   {a, 0, 2 Pi, 0.02}]
```

It's basically a rotated conch, and I wanted to make a gif of it. Turns out, it keeps aborting the evaluation without ever reporting an error, the CPU and RAM usage are negligible, and there's no indication my laptop can't handle the evaluation in a reasonable amount of time. Resetting the preferences doesn't help, so I'm at a loss. Is this a version bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please do not use `bugs` tag for unconfirmed issues.

Comment: Try storing the `Table` in a variable and suppress the output (by adding a `;`). The problem may be that _Mathematica_ is trying to display 600+ graphics simultaneously (as an output).

Comment: I think this may be `ParametricPlot3D` acting up. I was having similar problems working with a different question earlier today. I'm using 10.0.1.0 on OS X.

Comment: @JHM Already did that, and if I try to plot something simpler 600+ times, say a piece of a sphere, and let it output the result, it actually completes it. I don't see what's so special about the function in the post to make the kernel literally quit with no explanation.

Comment: Your code does work (at least on _Mathematica_ 10.1.0 on Windows (64-bit)). Try storing the `Table` in a variable and put a semicolon at the end. The computation takes several minutes to complete, though, due to its complexity. `Monitor` the variable `a` if you want to see progress.

Comment: @JHM again, I've stored it, and put the semicolon so it doesn't output, but the blue letters remain. The `Monitor` evaluates `a` a couple of times, most it's been was 0.12, then it aborts. The amount of loops it does is random though, once it stopped at 0.02, another 0.08 etc. Any other suggestions that might show more what's going on during evaluation?

Comment: That is indeed bizarre. An evaluation usually aborts (due to an error) before computations and after computations, not between them. Plus, the point where the abort occurs is inconsistent... If you haven't done so, try restarting _Mathematica_ / rebooting your computer. Also, what are your computer's specifications?

Comment: @blueshift, what happens when you run the following: `ListPlot[
 Last@Reap[
   Table[
    Sow[MemoryInUse[]];
    ParametricPlot3D[
     {a, u, v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -15, 6}
     ];, {a, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]
   ]
 ]`

Comment: @N.J.Evans that also makes the kernel abort! Okay, what's the deal with the code?

Comment: Try restarting the kernel and then setting the step size on `a` to 1. It looks like there might be a memory leak. Each subsequent time I run that code the memory usage goes up, when it gets high enough I get the kernel crash.

Comment: @N.J.Evans I tried rescaling the variable `a` to `2Pi a/100` in the plot and set the counter to `{a,0,100}`, but the kernel crashes again.

Comment: @blueshift, try fewer steps though. e.g. `{a,0, 2Pi, 1}` If it's a memory leak, then it's crashing when it runs out of memory, so you'd need to get it down to a smaller number of plots to see if memory is increasing with each additional plot.

Answer (score 4):

This was introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3.

```
curve1 = {Cos[φ] (4. - 1. Cos[4 φ] + 
      1. Cos[8 φ] - 1. Cos[12 φ]), (4. - 
      1. Cos[4 φ] + 1. Cos[8 φ] - 
      1. Cos[12 φ]) Sin[φ]};

curve2 = 2. - 1. Cos[4 φ];

tangent1 = D[curve1, φ];

surface = {{Cos[3 z], Sin[3 z], 0}, {-Sin[3 z], Cos[3 z], 0}, {0, 0, 
     1}}.Append[(1 - Sqrt[1 - Abs[z]]) (curve1 + 
       Reverse[tangent1 {-1, 1}]/Sqrt[tangent1.tangent1] curve2), z];

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[surface], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 1},
  Mesh -> 120, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very satisfactory answer, but it turns out that this exact same code works on version 10.4.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016) on the same OS and laptop, and as @JHM points out it works on a Windows machine, therefore I suspect this might be a version+OS specific bug. In any case, my problem is solved.

Answer (score -2):

Try Block

```
Block[{a},
    Table[ParametricPlot3D[{1.16^(v + a) Cos[(v + a)] (1 + 
    Cos[u]), -1.16^(v + a) Sin[(v + a)] (1 + 
    Cos[u]), -2 1.16^(v + a) (1 + Sin[u])}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -15, 
    6}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 3}, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2,
    ImageSize -> 500, Background -> None], {a, 0, 2 Pi, 0.02}]
    ]
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue because it is a problem with `Table` and `ParametricPlot3D`, not with the variable `a`.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it solved the problem.

Comment: Your issue may have been that `a` was defined outside of the code, thus affecting the `Table` loop. The OP's problem is not with the global definition of `a`, but instead a bizarre kernel behavior (random aborts). `Block` in this case simply is saying that the definition of `a` inside `Block` is separate from that outside of `Block`.

Comment: It worked when I applied to the OP's problem. I think it is an Linux issue.  I'm running Mathematica 10.0.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (Slackware).

Comment: OP's code should work fine even without the `Block`.